# How to redirect unzip -v output to a log file in shell script

Tags: shell-script, zip, stderr

I have a script that loops through all zip files in a large directory and individually unzips them. I am using the -q option in order to keep the console clean and display other monitoring info.

I would like to keep this same behavior but would like to add the output of the -v option to a single log file of the whole operation. What would be the best way of accomplishing this? Btw, I'm still a bit green when it comes to scripting so any input would be appreciated.

Unzip portion of script:

```
for FILES in $(ls -1Sr|grep a_media*)
 do unzip -q $FILES -d $DESTINATION
done
```

Answer (score 2):

You can redirect `stdout` and `stderr` for the whole loop:

```
for FILES in $(ls -1Sr|grep a_media*)
 do unzip -q "$FILES" -d "$DESTINATION"
done > log 2>&1
```

With at least `zsh` and recent versions of `bash` you can replace `> log 2>&1` with `>& log`.

Your `ls` processing is suspicious, see [Why *not* parse `ls`?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)...

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you to enclose the `$FILES` and `$DESTINATION` variables in the `unzip` command in double-quotes, since in case of paths containing spaces they will break the `unzip` command; also note that your script will break on filenames containing newlines, due to `ls` outputting the "raw" filenames containing the newlines to the pipe; use `bash`'s globbing feature instead (`for FILES in /path/to/archives/* [...]`).

Second, when you don't run `unzip` with the `-q` option, which suppresses the normal output, the output it's written to `stdout` (STDandard OUTput), which it's a file tipically linked to the terminal screen; shells such as `bash` can redirect the output of a command from `stdout` to another file: for example, in `bash`, this can be done via the `>` and `>>` operators, which respectively 1. Creates the file if not existing or truncates it then appends the output to it and 2. Creates the file if not existing or appends the output to it.

So in this case, since you're processing multiple archives, you don't want to truncate the log file each time a new file it's processed, but you rather want to append the new output to the already existing log; including my corrections:

```
for FILES in /path/to/archives/*
do
    unzip -v "$FILES" -d "$DESTINATION" >> /path/to/logfile
done
```

Comment: Thanks for all the info. I was taking a calculated risk by parsing `ls` because in a previous iteration of the script I was sorting before  unzipping the files from smallest to biggest, in a directory that the files always have a short reliable name (I have a different script that populates this dir). I have since abandoned that idea so `/path/to/archives/*` would work just perfectly. And I thought that `>>` would work but seemed like I was missing something. Thanks for clearing the `stdout` concept for me.